# UIToolbar with UITextView in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make `UITableView` with messages in bubble like iPhone message app. And I need to make  `UIToolBar` at the bottom of the screen with UITextView and button to send message, but the problem is that I have UITabBar on the bottom of the screen and I don't have an idea how to make this. It must look like `UIToolBar` in Skype application. Any help appreciated.

[image]

As you can see on the picture there is `UIToolBar` right under the `UITabBar` and fixed on it.

Comment: If you are using table view controller, instead use a view which has toolbar at the bottom and table view above it. Also in your xib/storyboard, set the top and bottom bars accordingly so that you can visually see it.

Comment: I have not even thought of making it in simple view controller instead of table view controller. Thanx for advice! If you can post your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using table view controller, instead use a view which has toolbar at the bottom and table view above it. Also in your xib/storyboard, set the top and bottom bars accordingly so that you can visually see it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you could see  [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=chat)  for chat like controls. The one above the UITabbar is not essentially a UIToolbar you could achieve this easily using a UIView too.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/thchatinput, does somehting every similar to what you say. What I would suggest is use a UIView which contains the textView and the send button and the emoji button to implement this .Using a UIToolbar could be a bit difficult because you have to add flexible space item and fixed space items etc. UIView would be a better choice buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Make a UIView and add UITextView as subview on it. On clicking it increase the frame size.